How to open File Explorer in specific directory and avoid unrelated apps?
I'm working on an Android app using Kotlin, and I need to open the file explorer at a specific directory where a file is located. Specifically, I want to open the "Documents" directory. Additionally, I want to make sure that only file explorer apps are shown as options and not other types of apps.
Here's the relevant code snippet I'm using:
private val documents = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

fun open() {
    val documentsUri = Uri.fromFile(documents)
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        data = documentsUri
        type = "*/*"
        flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    }
}

However, I'm encountering a couple of issues:

Unrelated apps showing up: when using the code above, on my Android
13 device, I see a lot of unrelated apps in the chooser, such as
Messenger, Signal, Gmail, etc. Only one file explorer app shows up
(although there should be more).

Opening the wrong folder: when selecting a file explorer, it opens
the "Downloads" folder instead of the "Documents" folder. This might
be due to how the file explorer app handles intents.



There is no standard Intent structure for what you seek, and there is no requirement for a device to have a file explorer app.

What you want isn't how Android works.  You're saying you want to view a file of any type.  That means any app that says it can open files will be displayed in the chooser.  There is no concept of a "file explorer app" built into Android.  When you choose an app to use, it will do whatever it wants.  I don't believe there is a standard way of saying what directory to open, and even if there was it could be ignored.  If that's really functionality you need, write your own file explorer.
